# sparse matrices solver for f90

Tags: matrix, gfortran, lapack, sparse-matrix

I am dealing with up to N=10^7 x N=10^7 matrices; number of nonzero elements is about 6 x N. (Those elements are grouped around diagonal.) My RAM has 16 Gbt size; so I clearly need sparse matrix solver. I run Ubuntu LINUX, and use fortran90 (gfortran), or precisely speaking, ratfor90.

I have LAPACK, but it doesn't seem to support sparse matrix solving. 
(am I wrong with that?) MATLAB must be good, but I don't want to spend much time to get familiar with it; the time is pressing. I have old/gold slatec installed and use it for spec. functions; does it have sparse matrix routins?

I hear about ARPACK, but can it be used as a plain solver? could it be called from gfortran?

Any other suggestion?

Thanks,    -- Alex

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Lapack is not applicable to this problem.

Direct Sparse solvers are provided by MUMPS, UMFPACK, SuperLU libraries.
Also PETSc is a library collection where you can find a lot of information

You can find Ubuntu package available for all these libraries.

Comment: any idea where I could start learning PETSc?

Comment: @amzon-ex I would suggest the PETSc users manual. It is rather extensive but if you narrow down your area of interest, it seems the better fit.

Answer (score 0):

ARPACK is a package that solves eigenvalue problems, but it is not a solver by itself.
I am not sure you can solve your problem on 16 Gb. I recommend having a look at freefem++

Comment: Thanks for the comment.freefem seems to be a great package for PDF solving, but it looks to be an overkill to get into it for only solve sparse matrices...